# cant get out parameter from stored procedure using php

Tags: php, oracle

I am getting array as a out parameter while executing this function to execute stored procedure.

```
function ExecuteProcedure($procedureName, $parameters)
{       $query = "begin " . $procedureName . "(" ;
    for($i=0; $i<count($parameters); $i++)
    {
        if($i==0)
            $query = $query . ":" . $parameters[$i][0] ;
        else
            $query = $query . ", :" . $parameters[$i][0] ;
    }

    $query = $query . "); end;"; 

    //echo $query . "<br />";

    $this->stmt = ociparse($this->con, $query) or die (ocierror()); 

    for($i=0; $i<count($parameters); $i++)
    {

        $valueList = $parameters[$i];
        if(count($valueList) == 2)
            ocibindbyname($this->stmt, $valueList[0], $valueList[1]) or die (ocierror()); 
        else if(count($valueList) == 3)
            ocibindbyname($this->stmt, $valueList[0], $valueList[1], $valueList[2]) or die (ocierror()); 
        else{
        ocibindbyname($this->stmt, $valueList[0], $valueList[1], $valueList[2], $valueList[3]) or die (ocierror()); 
        }
    }

    @ociexecute($this->stmt, OCI_DEFAULT) or die (ocierror()); 

    return $parameters;

}
```

Comment: You're doing `return $parameters;`? What's your `Procedure` supposed to do?

Comment: my procedure only insert values on table . I need id as a return value and i had set id as out_parameter on my procedure but I am not getting id as outparameter here

Comment: Can you share the procedure definition?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try with a simple example first, following the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) which contains info about OUT variables:

> You must specify maxlength when using an OUT bind so that PHP allocates enough memory to hold the returned value.

Build a simple procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo (p OUT VARCHAR2) IS 
BEGIN
   p := 'bar';
END foo;
```

Then in PHP:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'begin foo(:p1); end;');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p1', $p1, 3);
echo $p1;
```