# How to use a php variable in PL/SQL statement in Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I am trying to use a PHP variable instead of using Oracle Variable. Now the code is as follows:

```
declare
    V_EXAMCAT_MAP_ID varchar2(16);
begin
    PRC_BUILD_PK ('', 'SEQ_NM_APPLICATION', 'T', '1', V_EXAMCAT_MAP_ID,'Y');
end;
/
```

Now in the above code, V_EXAMCAT_MAP_ID is returning **T180801000010** I want to use PHP variable instead of **V_EXAMCAT_MAP_ID** to get the result in a PHP variable of the procedure.

Is it possible? if possible please help me

Comment: check this article https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html

Comment: duplicate of [cant get out parameter from stored procedure using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746612/cant-get-out-parameter-from-stored-procedure-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "Binding Parameters in PL/SQL Procedure Calls" on p192 of the free http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

For example, to get a string from a PL/SQL procedure 'OUT' parameter, you would use something like:

```
$s = oci_parse($c, "begin toyshop.find_toy_proc(:id, :name); end;");
$id = 1;
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":id", $id);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":name", $name, 40);
oci_execute($s);
echo "Name is: ".$name;
```